# Alternative to Cat out of a bash script?

Tags: arrays, linux, bash

i have an issue with the following.

```
exec 3<>/dev/tcp/$1/37491

echo -ne 060e2b3 00$hexdec$cmdhex | perl -pe 's/([0-9a-f]{2})/chr hex $1/gie' >&3

cat <&3
```

i have a server in which i send a hex string to with the port / tcp connection made. BUT since i am using putty through a terminal my first issue is that the XML response back always says PuTTY and it doesnt escape. I also need to put the replies back sometimes in an array and i have tried

```
array=`cat <&3`

echo "Array items:"
for item in ${array[*]}
do
    printf "   %s\n" $item
done
```

and i believe since the cat is not exiting properly it just stays open the array is not done?

thanks for the advanced help

Comment: Perhaps you want to try `read array <&3` instead, in a loop, to process line-by-line (assuming responses are line-terminated, anyway)...

Comment: @twalberg  thank you. Can you help me with the below? During answers i cannot comment back to the direct person. i am not sure where he wants me to place exec 3>&-

Comment: i tried adding this. while read line <&3
do {
  echo "$line"
  (( Lines++ ));                    
}
done
exec 3>&-

Answer (score 2):

Do you need specify a timeout?

```
while read -t 5 line <&3; do 
    echo "$line"
    (( Lines++ ))
done
exec 3>&-
```

Comment: THANK YOU!, that finally worked. gave it a time out of 2 seconds and worked.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need to close the TCP/IP socket?

```
exec 3>&-
```

Comment: I tried the above. i finally saw how to use it because i researched it. (DUH) but even using that AFTER the cat <&3 it keeps the session open no matter even if i have the close right after the cat.