# Cannot End Bash Script with stdout exec

Tags: linux, bash, exec

I Do not know why my Questions dont get follow up after posting comments. BUT i have tried to use

exec 3>&- to exit out of a cat <&3 and still nothing

i have also tried cat <&3 3>&- still wont work

```
exec 3<>/dev/tcp/$1/37491

echo -ne 060e2b3400$hexdec$cmdhex | perl -pe 's/([0-9a-f]{2})/chr hex $1/gie' >&3

cat <&3
exec 3>&-
```

the socket remains open.

Comment: Does `cat` ever return allowing the final `exec` to be executed? It may still be waiting for more input to arrive via the socket.

Comment: @chepner it does, but will not close or end unless i press ctrl+c. if i run the exec 3<&- command before the cat it closes it b/c the cat will then say invalid.

Comment: I googled the exec command's etc for use in stdin and out and closing none of the combinations works

Comment: So if you put an `echo` statement between the `cat` and the `exec`, you'll see its output?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Alternative to Cat out of a bash script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20661320/alternative-to-cat-out-of-a-bash-script)

Comment: @glennjackman yes that is me. no1 is seeing my replies etc. I cannot use echo to get the info from <&3 atleast i dont know of an alternative way. i will google

Comment: @chepner if i put the echo after the cat it wont output b/c it will not escape from the cat open socket.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing you add after the `cat` will work, because `cat` is blocking, waiting for more input over the socket. If you can arrange to close the socket from another process, `cat` will exit.

Something like the following may work:

```
exec 3<>/dev/tcp/$1/37491

echo -ne 060e2b3400$hexdec$cmdhex | perl -pe 's/([0-9a-f]{2})/chr hex $1/gie' >&3

( cat <&3; echo "Socket was closed" ) &
sleep 10
exec 3>&-
```

The `cat` will run in the background in a subshell, blocking until the socket is closed. After sleeping for 10 seconds, your script will close the socket, and you should see the output "Socket was closed".